# How to extract strings from a json_encode array in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a php file which shows the username & password for a userID (via a mysql query). The userID is sent via jquery. I used json_encode to combine the username & password as an array. But when I attempt to extract the strings (username & password) from that combined (array) It seems that "whole array" was returned. How can I extract the strings (username & password) from a json_encoded array? These are my code snippets.

This is the file display.php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $ID=$_POST['id'];
    $userQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid ='".$ID."'");
    $UserArray = mysql_fetch_array($userQuery);
    $username=$UserArray[1];
    $passWord=$UserArray[2];
    $combinedArray = array($username,$passWord);
    echo json_encode(combinedArray);
}
?>
```

This is the JQuery which gets the strings from the combined array...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "display.php",
        data:{id:userID},
        success: function(returnedData)
        {
            $("#userNameDiv").html(returnedData);
            $("#passWordDiv").html(returnedData);
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

And this is the combined array as it displays...

```
["anandan2345","appleMac2015"]
["anandan2345","appleMac2015"]
```

But I need these strings in two separate variables...

Could anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean by strings in two separate variables... ?

Comment: I think you want to display the username in the username div's only and password in the password div's?

Comment: @aldrin27: You got it..!

Comment: Why would you show a password? Passwords should always be hashed using a one-way algorithm like bcrype; it should be impossible to read a database and get a valid password from it. If your passwords are readable, then you are breaking pretty much every security best-practice there is. And you should certainly not be giving details from your users table without verifying that the request is legitimate (ie from the account owner); just querying the userid like that without any other checks means that anyone could read anyone else's account details just by guessing the userid. Ouch.

Comment: The other thing you need to be made aware of is that the `mysql_xxx()` functions in PHP are deprecated (and will be removed entirely in the next release of the language). You should stop using them, and switch to using either the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries instead.

Comment: Can you please print_r($UserArray); ?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 json_decode()
```

to decode the json value

For example, If $combinedArray has the resultant value as below:

```
$combinedArray = array(["anandan2345","appleMac2015"]);
$temp = json_encode($combinedArray);
$tempres= json_decode($temp);
for($i=0;$i<count($tempres);$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<count($tempres[$i]);$j++)
    {
        echo $tempres[$i][$j].'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example to eliminate the unwanted characters form that combined array, using json_decode() ?

Comment: Please give me the resulting array that you are getting without decode. I will show you how to do

Comment: ["anandan2345","appleMac2015"]

Answer (score 2):

This should work. returnedData is an array of two items. You just must need to insert each item on it's own div.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        url: "display.php",
        data:{id:userID},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(returnedData)
        {
            $("#userNameDiv").html(returnedData[0]);
            $("#passWordDiv").html(returnedData[1]);
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this too... but the array-index gives a 'single character' only... It seems that 'returnedData' is a string as I saw.. ["anandan2345","appleMac2015"]

Comment: I've updated my answer. I added the parameter: 'dataType': json because jquery it's currently parsing returnedData as txt.

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the blow code :

```
success: function (returnedData) {
    $("#userNameDiv").html(returnedData);
    $("#passWordDiv").html(returnedData);
}
```

such as the jquery function `$.each()` to fit your need.You can [click here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to learn the `$.each`.

Comment: Sorry... Couldn't understand. You mean $.each(returnedData) ..?

Answer (score 0):

Oh my dear friends... I achieved..!

I avoid the "json_encoded" & used "implode" function in php to concatenate those username & password as following.

```
$combinedArray = array($username,$passWord);
echo implode("2015",$combinedArray );
```

Then in the Jquery, I use the 'split' method as following...

```
var mystr = returnedData;  
/*returndata is the concatenated string echoed by php*/
var myarr = mystr.split("2015");
var un = myarr[0];
var pw = myarr[1];
```

Now I'm having those two strings as 'un' & 'pw'

1000s of Thanks for your valued contribution...!

I have to thank especially @Simba... for his/her greatest advice...!